# reset dropzone or remove allfiles when dropzone clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, dropzone.js

I'm using this code

```
Dropzone.options.demoUpload = {
    addRemoveLinks:true,
    maxFilesize:200, //in MB
    maxFiles:2, //Shows message You Can only upload two files
    clickable:true
  };
```

The problem is when i upload 2 files it prevents me from uploading more files. I want the rule that only two files can be dropped at one time but Is there a way i can reset the dropzone when i click on it . So that another two files can be uploaded..

I have done this in `drop:function(){}` //removed all files

But dont know how to do this when clicked on dropzone reset it

Comment: Do you want to only accept the first two dropped or only accept a drop if two or less are dropped?